# Convert C# project into Dll for C++ project

Tags: c#, c++, windows, visual-studio-2005

I am a newbie to C#. I am currently working on learning C# code. My final goal is to convert a C# project into a dll so that I can use it in my C++ exe. I am using VS2005.

I was wondering if it's possible and if so I would appreciate for some guidance and suggestions in this regards,

Please do reply back,

Answer (score 3):

Why not to make a com object out of your managed lib and call it from the unmanaged c++ code? It's relatively easy to do if you know how to manage com in c++..
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645736(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: - Thank you so much for your quick reply. My C++ exe takes DLL's ( dynamic linking ) on the run time. I don't want to change the C++ exe code but if i can compile C# code ( which is a wrapper ) into a dll with few function mappings to match that my C++ exe code is looking for would be awesome...:)

Answer (score 1):

Write a C++/CLI wrapper around the C# DLL that exposes a native C++ interface to the C# code.

You'll probably need to enable the `/clr` flag in your application, but there are ways to expose a completely native interface via a DLL too.

There is a good explanation and sample implementation of the various techniques at [this link](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/sasha/archive/2008/02/16/net-to-c-bridge.aspx).