# How to call a function in an unmanaged dll from C# Code?

Tags: c#, c++, dllimport, lpbyte

How can I call the following method from C#, which is in a C++ dll? How Can I recreate  the following structure in C#?

---

**Original**

***Method:***

```
LONG MyMethod (P_HOLO_INFO pInfo, LPVOID pBuffer, LPUSHORT pTracksWritten);
```

***Structure:*** This method uses the following structure:

```
typedef struct _HOLO_INFO
{
    LONG     lHoloType;
    LONG     lStatus;
    HANDLE   lThreadHandle;
    LONG     lErrorCode;
    LONG     lDriveIndex;
    LONG     lHeight;
    SHORT    iFormat;
    INT      iStartingTrack;
    LONG     lWrite;
    LONG     lSkip;
    BOOL     bSkipZero;
    BOOL     bInvert;
    LONG     lMaxConsecutiveErrors;
    LONG     lMaxTotalErrors;
    LONG     lMostConsecutiveErrors; 
    LONG     lTotalErrors;
    LPBYTE   pBuffer;
    LPUSHORT pTracksWritten;
    LONG     bUpsideDown;
} HOLO_INFO, *P_HOLO_INFO;
```

---

**I worked in C# like this**

***Method:***

```
[DllImport("My.dll", EntryPoint = "_MyMethod@12")]
public unsafe static extern long MyMethod(ref HOLO_INFO pInfo, Byte[] pBuffer,ref ushort pTracksWritten);
```

***Structure:***

This method uses the following structure:

```
unsafe public  struct HOLO_INFO 
{
    public long  lHoloType;
    public long  lStatus;
    public long  lThreadHandle;
    public ulong lErrorCode;
    public long  lDriveIndex;
    public long  lHeight;
    public short iFormat;
    public int   iStartingTrack;
    public long  lWrite;
    public long  lSkip;
    public bool  bSkipZero;
    public bool  bInvert;
    public long  lMaxConsecutiveErrors;
    public long  lMaxTotalErrors;
    public long  lMostConsecutiveErrors; 
    public long  lTotalErrors;
    public Byte* pBuffer;
    public long* pTracksWritten;
    public long  bUpsideDown;
};
```

***I made a call to the method like this:***

```
  do
  {
    result = MyMethod(ref pInfo,ptrBuf,pTracksWritten);
  } while (result ==1 );
```

Because, it returns 1, if it is Active
                    0, if it completed successfully
                    3, if it stopped because of error.
if the method is in running state(Active-1). it modifies **pInfo** and **pTracksWritten** to update the status information.

Comment: I had to do something similar a while back. What I did was wrap the dll in a CLRC++ class and get the C++ struct on one side and returned the CLR compatible struct on the other side, but this was a while back, maybe there is a better method now.

Comment: You are clearly on the right track here. If I were you I would write a special test function in C++ to iron out the details. Get it to write out the input to a file. You can then check that what you are sending from C# is correct. For any data pass in the other direction, get the test C# program to log to file also.

Answer (score 3):

Lots of issues:

- LONG should be declared as int in C#
- HANDLE is IntPtr.
- pTracksWritten is missing.  You probably need to make it, and pBuffer, an IntPtr and use Marshal.AllocHGlobal to allocate memory for them, depends.
- You need the CallingConvention in the [DllImport] declaration to use Cdecl.

Odds of getting this to work are not great if you can't debug the unmanaged code.  One basic sanity test is to make sure that Marshal.SizeOf() returns the same length as sizeof() in the unmanaged code.  Next verify that passed arguments look good when debugging the native code.  Next triple-check the pointer usage in the native code and verify that they are not getting copied.

Comment: If possible, Please please provide a complete answer. I spent many days for this by searching and trying differently. Many thanks for your quick response.

Comment: I just hand you the proper caliber bullets.  Pointing the gun at your foot is what you get paid to do.  Doing this in C++/CLI would be advisable.

Comment: Agreed, CallingConvention should probably be omitted.

Answer (score 0):

See [Using a Very C# DLL in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5519128/using-a-very-c-dll-in-c/5519337#5519337)

You can do a 'simple' trick [this answer](answer [Using a Very C# DLL in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5519128/using-a-very-c-dll-in-c/5519686#5519686)) or you can have a look at fullblown embedding as per [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5519128/using-a-very-c-dll-in-c/5519337#5519337)

Comment: I need to use a C++ dll in C#.

Comment: I must have been sleeping. There is a VS addin to translate C proto + declarations into P/Invoke stuff... if I've got time I'll find it again

Comment: @aWebdesigner09 : The title was misleading and sounded like you wanted the reverse. I edited it.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot:

```
[DllImport("My.dll", EntryPoint = "_MyMethod@12")]
int MyMethod (HOLO_INFO pInfo, IntPtr pBuffer, IntPtr pTracksWritten);

public class HOLO_INFO
{
    public int    lHoloType;
    public int    lStatus;
    public IntPtr lThreadHandle;
    public int    lErrorCode;
    public int    lDriveIndex;
    public int    lHeight;
    public short  iFormat;
    public int    iStartingTrack;
    public int    lWrite;
    public int    lSkip;
    public bool   bSkipZero;
    public bool   bInvert;
    public int    lMaxConsecutiveErrors;
    public int    lMaxTotalErrors;
    public int    lMostConsecutiveErrors; 
    public int    lTotalErrors;
    public IntPtr pBuffer;
    public IntPtr pTracksWritten;
    public int    bUpsideDown;
}
```

Depending on how they're allocated, you may need to use [`Marshal.Copy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146631.aspx) to access `HOLO_INFO.pBuffer` and [`Marshal.PtrToStructure`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4ca6d5z7.aspx) to access `HOLO_INFO.pTracksWritten` (or [`Marshal.Copy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146634.aspx) if it's an array vs. a pointer to a singular value).

Comment: calling convention will be stdcall

Comment: And you surely mean: `int MyMethod (ref HOLO_INFO Info, IntPtr pBuffer, out UInt16 TracksWritten);`

Comment: @David Heffernan : No on all counts. `DllImport`'s default calling convention is stdcall, but VC++'s default is cdecl (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/46t77ak2.aspx). Regarding `ref`, `HOLO_INFO` is a `class` so it is already passed by reference; using `ref` there would be akin to `HOLO_INFO**` or `P_HOLO_INFO*` in C++. Regarding `out ushort`, it appears to me that `HOLO_INFO.pTracksWritten` may end up holding that pointer value, which will be invalid after the function returns if an explicit heap allocation isn't used.

Comment: function name with @12 suggests strongly that stdcall is used. Surely you use a struct rather than a class? HOLO_INFO.pTracksWritten is very odd though. This is one of those questions that is impossible to answer fully because so much detail is missing.

Comment: @David Heffernan : Rereading the other comments now, I see your point regarding the mangled name; I'll edit to omit the `CallingConvention`.

Comment: @David Heffernan : Regarding `struct` vs. `class`, Rico Mariani's long standing recommendation is to not create `struct`s greater than 16 bytes in size. Given that the semantics of passing a `struct` with `ref` vs. passing a `class` without `ref` should be the same, a type of this size seems to me more reasonable as a `class` in CLR-land.

Comment: @ildjarn I didn't know that. What's wrong with struct's >16 bytes?

Comment: @David Heffernan : Purely a performance recommendation on his part, nothing technically "wrong".

Comment: @ildjarn I reproduced like this. But it is not working. I am editing the Question for further understanding.

Comment: I am getting garbage values as retrun values into the varible 'result'